# Bottom of Website Whited Out in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a weird problem on one of the sites I'm currently working on, and it seems to only happen on Chrome (Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)).

When I load a page, everything appears fine, but as I scroll down, part of the website is just completely whited out, as per this image:
[image: Student's Union of Calgary]

When the user adjusts the size of the browser, either bigger or smaller, the content shows up, but obviously this isn't a solution.

Here is a link to the website:
https://www.su.ucalgary.ca

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by setting the height of `body,html` to `auto`, rather than `100%`. Not 100% sure why that worked.